# Compiling Artimagen - library check error lua5.1 not found

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, failed-installation

I'm attemting to compile an image suite called Artimagen. It is designed to use the GNU Autotools toolkit. When I attempt to configure I get an error:

```
configure: error: fftw3 check failed
```

I have libfftw3-3 installed in place of fftw3. I have tried to install fftw3 but I am directed to libfftw3-3.

In the configure file can I update the fftw3 library check to libfftw3-3?
Also how do I do that?

```
# Checks for libraries.
AC_CHECK_LIB([tiff], [TIFFOpen], [TIFFLIB=-ltiff],
AC_MSG_ERROR([libtiff check failed]))
AC_SUBST([TIFFLIB])

AC_CHECK_LIB([fftw3], [fftw_execute], [FFTW3LIB=-lfftw3],
AC_MSG_ERROR([fftw3 check failed]))
AC_SUBST([FFTW3LIB])

AS_IF([test "x$with_threads" != xno],
[
AC_CHECK_LIB([fftw3_threads], [fftw_init_threads], 
  [FFTW3TLIB="-lfftw3_threads -lm -lpthread"]
  [AC_DEFINE([HAVE_FFTW3_THREADS], [1], [Define if you have fftw3_threads])]
  [have_fftw3_threads=yes],
AC_MSG_ERROR([fftw3 check failed]),[-lfftw3 -lpthread -lm])
AC_SUBST([FFTW3TLIB])
])

AM_CONDITIONAL(HAVE_FFTW3_THREADS, test x$have_fftw3_threads = xyes)
```

**(edit)**

have attempted to install the library fftw3 found here [fftw3](http://www.fftw.org/download.html), in attempting to install I get the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 fftw3.h fftw3.f fftw3l.f03 fftw3q.f03     '/usr/local/include'
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file     '/usr/local/include/fftw3.h': Permission denied
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file     '/usr/local/include/fftw3.f': Permission denied
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file     '/usr/local/include/fftw3l.f03': Permission denied
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file     '/usr/local/include/fftw3q.f03': Permission denied
Makefile:553: recipe for target 'install-includeHEADERS' failed
make[3]: *** [install-includeHEADERS] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/vanoccupanther/Desktop/fftw-    3.3.4/api'
Makefile:692: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/vanoccupanther/Desktop/fftw-    3.3.4/api'
Makefile:686: recipe for target 'install' failed
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/vanoccupanther/Desktop/fftw-3.3.4/api'
Makefile:632: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

could someone help me understand these errors?

**(edit1)**

I fixed the above error but another popped up...

**(edit2)**

The configuration of this Artimagen is now telling me that a dependency lua5.1 is not found. I have installed lua5.1 a few minutes ago.

My thinking is that maybe the artimagen program is looking for lua in the wrong directory.

config.log:

```
configure:14754: checking for main in -llua5.1
configure:14773: gcc -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c -llua5.1   >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llua5.1
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:14773: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
```

shell:

```
checking for main in -llua5.1... no
configure: error: in `/home/vanoccupanther/Desktop/artimagen-0.91':
configure: error: lua test failed (--without-lua to disable)
See `config.log' for more details.
```

the lua program installed to my comp on /usr/bin
while the artimagen config.log is saying it can't find lua on /usr/bin/ld

Could this be the issue?

(As an FWI, I'm a physics student not a programmer)

Comment: Did you try (on a copy) changing to `...., [FFTW3LIB=-lfftw3-3]` ? Hmm . and `3-3`? What about `3.3`? Good luck.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet as I am unsure what to do and do not want to break anything but I'll give it a go. Thanks.

Comment: ok tried that no joy, same error.

Comment: where there instructions in a README.txt (or INSTALL.txt, or similar) file for installing the lib? Did you use `sudo install ... ` ? Permissions denied sounds like you tried running this as a non-root user. (In about 10 mins, going to be away for a while). Good luck.

Comment: arg, remove old error and show new error ;-) . Leaving in 5 mins. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah it took me all of 2 secs to see I needed to root. New error now is saying that a dependency lua5.1 is not found, even though I just installed the thing. Thanks though!

Comment: OK, I hope you're up and running (or getting there). Will check back later. Good luck.

Comment: Show actual error messages, as you have done before. It helps! Bye for now. Good luck.

Comment: if you're refering to line 3 of the config log, `/usr/bin/ld` is a program that is trying to find/use `lua5.1`. So your guess seems right, that you haven't installed it the place the config test expects to find it. I would try to make a local connection with someone that can help you get this up and running, otherwise we'll be playing "40 questions" to get all this resolved. Did you use `sudo` to install `lua`? I think you probably should, unless there is a note in the README or INSTALL files for that package (or other well described reason). Going out again. Good luck.

Comment: cheers for getting back to me, I didn't do sudo install with Lua, I'll uninstall and try again. Trying to find someone local but I don't know too many coders.